# How to modify Last Write Time and Last Access on folder

Tags: powershell

We need to change the folder attributes in relation to Last Write Time and Last Access on lots of folders on the server.

We found away to do this by running Powershell as follow:

```
set-itemproperty -Path C:\testsource\folder1 -Name LastWriteTime -Value ((get-date).adddays(-90))
```

As you can see the get-date method is adding adddays stuff. Is there any function that can sets the exactly as "2013-05-03 11:31" upto a minute ?

The reason is that I had this exact date for instance from previous backup "2013-05-03 11:31" and need to be replaced "2015-03-12 18:31" as you can see if it's very challenge to set addminute cause we are dealing with hundreds folder.

Thanks for the input.

Comment: So your question really is "How do I parse `2013-05-03 11:31` in to DateTime object so it can be passed in to `-Value`" (Also did you just try `-Value '2013-05-03 11:31'`?)

Comment: Correct. I haven't tested that actually.

Comment: Try to create a DateTime object beforehand, and use the -Date parameter. See [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx) as reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the `LastWriteTime` attribute reset to a specific (fixed) timestamp simply pass it as a string, as @ScottChamberlain said in the comments to your question:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path C:\testsource\folder1 -Name LastWriteTime -Value '2013-05-03 11:31'
```

Passing a date value is also possible (see answer provided by [@AmrAyman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31237626/1630171)), but normally you only want to take that extra step if you need to do date calculations. For instance, if you want the date reset to a specific time relative to the current day, you could do something like this:

```
$date = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-90).AddHours(11).AddMinutes(31)
Set-ItemProperty -Path C:\testsource\folder1 -Name LastWriteTime -Value $date
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a DateTime object beforehand (for efficiency, before the loop) using this syntax:

```
$date = Get-Date "5/3/2013 11:31 AM"
```

And in the `-Value` parameter, pass in `$date`.